# Textures show up as black in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

[Here's the .blend file.](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aluy-BxLZdSrhHOPj0EGMw5Ciq-9?e=uO1aZH) [Rock texture used](https://cc0textures.com/view?id=Rock032) I have the edges of the plane set to emission and tried to set the bottom face to a rock texture but when I added the texture it showed up as black in cycles. It works in eevee. How can i fix this?

Comment: Connect the normal map with a Normal Map node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to me that you forgot to plug in a bump node with the bump texture[image: vvv]

check the vid
https://youtu.be/HUDOU7gSOwE

Comment: That fixed it, and a few other black objects. Thanks!